# Multiple count distincts in Impala

Tags: distinct, impala

I need to find out the difference between number of distinct patients between given time periods.

the table is in impala in parquet format.

Is there a better way to write this query.  both the select queries uses same table.

a patient has to be counted only once for a given set of time periods

```
WITH
 curr_prod AS 
(
    SELECT    product 
             ,COUNT(DISTINCT(patient_id)) AS rawPatientCount 
    FROM      tbl 
    WHERE     time_seq_id IN (12,11,10) 
    GROUP BY  product
)
,prev_prod AS 
(
    SELECT   product
            ,COUNT(DISTINCT(patient_id)) AS rawPatientCount 
    FROM     tbl 
    WHERE    time_seq_id in (7,8,9) 
    GROUP BY product
)
SELECT       COALESCE(curr_prod.product,prev_prod.product) AS product,
            ,curr_prod.rawPatientCount-prev_prod.rawPatientcount AS change_pat_cnt
FROM         curr_prod 
FULL OUTER JOIN prev_prod ON curr_prod.product=prev_prod.product
```

Comment: Can you show us the database schema? And clarify what you mean by "better"? Do you want it formatted differently? Does it need to be more performant? What's wrong with with what you already have, and how would you like to improve upon it?

Comment: we are trying to run the query over a billion rows table. the two inner queries read from same table. Only the time period is the change. Im trying to see if i can hit the table only once by any chance or  want to make peace with myself that each time a count distinct is needed in impala a separate query has to written'd .